# Reaver can't crack wi-fi stuck on the same pin (12345670)

Tags: wifi, aircrack-ng

I'm trying to crack my own wi-fi through WPS using reaver using `sudo reaver -i wlan0 -b 84:9F:B5:71:48:28 -vv` and it keeps outputting these messages repeatedly.
I'm using tp link wn722n wireless adapter v3. It supports monitor mode and packet injection (after a bit of exhaustion). There's one thing that doesn't work on this adapter which is changing its mac address (don't know if that would be useful or not).

I left it for 10 hours and it's still like that.

The problem is the with the error (WPS transaction failed (code: 0x02), re-trying last pin) and that it's stuck on the same pin (12345670)

P.S: I'm a bit of a newbie to linux, so please make your answer detailed.

```
[+] Waiting for beacon from 20:E8:82:AE:36:76
[+] Switching wlan0 to channel 1
[+] Received beacon from 20:E8:82:AE:36:76
[+] Vendor: RealtekS
[+] Trying pin "12345670"
[+] Sending authentication request
[+] Sending association request
[+] Associated with 20:E8:82:AE:36:76 (ESSID: WE_AE3676)
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[!] WARNING: 10 successive start failures
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[+] Sending WSC NACK
[!] WPS transaction failed (code: 0x02), re-trying last pin
```

Comment: How long have you waited with it spitting out those messages?  That seems an odd piece of information to miss from your question so I'll point out the manual says it takes between 4-10 hours on average: https://tools.kali.org/wireless-attacks/reaver

Comment: What is your problem? What do you expect that is not happening?

Comment: @Panki: A. He cannot crack his WiFi sucessfully. B. Something on the likes of "WPS transaction successful" or no errors so that the cracking can finish. I honestly cannot see what's unclear here.

Comment: @X.LINK expecting WPS to be cracked in within a few attempts is unreasonable, to say the least. Also, there are no errors here - only warnings.

Comment: I don't think he expected to succeed that quick, it's more likely about things not keeping up or giving him back any results, positive or not.

Comment: The problem is the with the error (WPS transaction failed (code: 0x02), re-trying last pin) and that it's stuck on the same pin (12345670) and keeps outputting the above code over and over again. Is this normal?

Answer (score 3):

On an older version of the code there is a known issue where it just uses pin 12345670 (https://github.com/chrsmithdemos/reaver-wps/issues/267).  From what I can see Kali distributes a fork of the code but I don't see the same issue listed in the new fork's issues:

- Reaver package on kali described here https://tools.kali.org/wireless-attacks/reaver
- references this fork https://github.com/t6x/reaver-wps-fork-t6x

You might like to try [raising an issue on the new fork](https://github.com/t6x/reaver-wps-fork-t6x/issues), explaining the problem clearly including **explicitly** stating the pin is stuck on 12345670.